# Find cumulative distribution function of a continuous random variable.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ is a random variable with density $f(x)=0.5e^{-|x|}, (-\infty<x<\infty)$. Find c.d.f of $x^2$.
I dont quite get the hang of these. I tried for just x and got the following.

for $x<0$:

$\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{2}e^x = \frac{1}{2}e^x$

for $x>0$:

$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^x \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}+1$


I tried the same thing for $x^2$ but got strange answers. Either im forgetting my calculus or going about the equations incorrectly. A little help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your CDF for $f(x)$ is incorrect because of two issues:

1. $|x|=x$ when $x \ge 0$ and $|x|=-x$ when $x \le 0$.
2. When you are finding out the cdf for $x\ge 0$ you need to split the cdf calculation from $-\infty$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $x$.

Perhaps, once you fix these two issues, you will make progress for $x^2$.